# Getting range of data from Excel returning an Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have an Excel file, I want to import it to as SQL Server table but from a specific range Sheet `'Shipment Profile$C15:DZ239'` like below :

[image]

I get the following error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotes in the OpenRowset like below :

```
Shipment Profile$C15:DZ239
```